# Pin image from drawables

Tags: android, pinterest

In Pinterest integration for Android, is it possible to pin images from the drawables?
Because setImageUrl sets image from a website, and setImageUri sets image from the sd card, what if it is just in the phone memory?

Comment: i know nothing about pinterest, but you can most likely use custom content provider uri to set your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So setImageUri can set images from local storage, afterall. Thank you :)